# How do I lazily pass csv rows to executemany()?

Tags: python, csv, python-db-api, executemany

I'm using MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.11 with Python 3.3 and MySQL 5.6.12 to load a csv file into a table via [cursor.executemany](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany)('INSERT INTO ... VALUES'). With sqlite3 or psycopg2 I can pass a _csv.reader object for seq_of_parameters, but MySQL fails with:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be list or tuple.
```

Fair enough, as the docs say it must be a sequence, and the [_csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object is an [enumerator](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (it defines **iter** and **next**), not a sequence. I could obviously pass 'list(my_csv_reader)', but I'm pretty sure that is not lazy, and these files can have 10^6+ rows. Is there a way to pass that lazily? Or am I wasting my time because executemany() will expand the list before performing the INSERT? (A hint from cursor.py: "INSERT statements are optimized by batching the data, that is using the MySQL multiple rows syntax.") Maybe something like wrapping the iterator in a generator, ala http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01193268742 . I'm very much looking forward to your thoughts!